# amalgamated free product of von Neumann algebras

Tags: group-theory, von-neumann-algebras

If $G$ and $H$ are two discrete groups and $L(G)$ and $L(H)$ be their group von Neumann algebras and $A$ be their common *-subalgebra, what can we say about their amalgamated free product under $A$, i. e $L(G)*_{A}L(H)$?
Does it embed in some $L(\Gamma)$ as a subalgebra? I actually want to know some more about this structure and  what group von Neumann algebras it may be embedded in?